# Kubernetes API Server KUBE_SERVICE_ADDRESSES parameter and Pod Network configuration

Tags: kubernetes, configuration

## Question

Where is the Kubernetes documentation regarding KUBE_SERVICE_ADDRESSES parameter of API server and Pod network configuration?

### Background

KUBE_SERVICE_ADDRESSES parameter value needs to go hand-in-hand with CIDR configuration of the Pod network, because `KUBE_SERVICE_ADDRESSES` is
"Address range to use for services" and I suppose `services` communicate in the Pod network.

Trying to find out a Kubernetes document which explains it but looks no specific documentation. Please suggest if this is true and where is the documentation related.

**/etc/kubernetes/apiserver**

```
# The address on the local server to listen to.
#KUBE_API_ADDRESS="--insecure-bind-address=127.0.0.1"
KUBE_API_ADDRESS="--insecure-bind-address=0.0.0.0"

# The port on the local server to listen on.
# KUBE_API_PORT="--port=8080"

# Port minions listen on
# KUBELET_PORT="--kubelet-port=10250"

# Comma separated list of nodes in the etcd cluster
KUBE_ETCD_SERVERS="--etcd-servers=http://127.0.0.1:2379"

# Address range to use for services
KUBE_SERVICE_ADDRESSES="--service-cluster-ip-range=10.254.0.0/16"

# default admission control policies
KUBE_ADMISSION_CONTROL="--admission-control=NamespaceLifecycle,NamespaceExists,LimitRanger,SecurityContextDeny,ServiceAccount,ResourceQuota"
```

### Related sites

[Using kubeadm to Create a Cluster (3/4) Installing a pod network](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/independent/create-cluster-kubeadm/#pod-network) says specific CIDR needs to be specified to `kubeadm init` as a option `--pod-network-cidr`.

[Deploy a Multi-node Kubernetes Cluster on CentOS 7](https://devops.profitbricks.com/tutorials/deploy-a-multi-node-kubernetes-cluster-on-centos-7/):

> Create a flannel-config.json file that will define the Flannel settings. The subnet specified in the Flannel settings should match that of the API server KUBE_SERVICE_ADDRESSES value. This is the subnet that the containers will use.

Answer (score 3):

https://kubernetes.io/docs/getting-started-guides/centos/centos_manual_config/

> ```
> # Address range to use for services
> KUBE_SERVICE_ADDRESSES="--service-cluster-ip-range=10.254.0.0/16"
> ```